# bilinear forms on $M_{n, n}(K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Let $K$ be a field and $V = M_{n, n}(K)$ the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over $K$. For any $f \in V^*$ (the dual space of $V$), we set:

$\gamma_f: V \times V \to K, (A, B) \mapsto f(A B^t)$.

I now first want to show that $\gamma_f$ is a bilinear form. Furthermore, I want to prove that:

$\Gamma: V^* \to Bil(V), f \mapsto \gamma_f$

is linear and injective. (Where ($Bil(V)$ is the set of bilinear forms from $V \times V$ to $K$.)

Thanks in advance. Bilinear forms are new to me, especially when it comes to working with them in regards to matrices.